# checking Directed Graph for bridges

Tags: algorithm, graph

i am looking for a fast Algorithm just to determine if a given directed graph contains a bridge or not ... 

not concerned about the location of this bridge .. only whether the graph contains it or not.

Comment: Just look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: @harold it's a directed graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've just found a better or simpler solution for that .. 
choose any node run a simple dfs and check if every node is visited then reverse all the edges and starting from the same node check if you can visit all the nodes again if not then it surely contains a Bridge.

Comment: Yes, but the complexity of this is O(E*E) whereas it's possible to do it in O(E)

Answer (score 4):

In case the graph is directed, analogously to the bridges for an undirected graph, we call an edge *strong bridge* if its removal increases the number of strongly connected components of a graph. 
In order to test whether a directed graph has strong bridges you need to run the algorithm detailed in the paper:
Giuseppe F. Italiano, Luigi Laura, Federico Santaroni: *Finding strong bridges and strong articulation points in linear time*. Theor. Comput. Sci. 447: 74-84 (2012)
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2011.11.011

Answer (score 1):

Note that an edge is a bridge if and only if it is not contained in any cycle, so if your graph is not strongly connected it should contain bridges.

Run the [Tarjan strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%E2%80%99s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) on your graph . if the result is different that your graph there is a bridge.

Comment: i know about this Algorithm .. but i thought there would be an easier way to do this since i don't want the location of the bridge ...i just want to check if it's Strongly connected or not ...

Comment: @AhmadIbrahem I believe it's the fastest way to do it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

Comment: @SaeedAmiri If the graph is strongly connected, all edges are contained in a cycle

Comment: What if there are parallel directed edges that are not a part of any cycle? I don't think these edges would classify as a bridge.